# Watching a computed attribute in VueJS

Tags: javascript, mvvm, vue.js

In my project I have a form that can only be submitted when certain fields are filled in, so I've created the canSubmit function in my ViewModel:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    data: {
        experiments: [],
        genes: ""
    },
    el: "html",
    computed: {
        canSubmit: function () {
            switch (this.searchType) {
                case "":
                    return false;
                case "gene":
                    return this.genes.length > 0 && this.experiments.length > 0;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I also have a button that I want to show if canSubmit returns true, and some `<inputs>` that change the data model:

```
<textarea v-model="genes" name="genes" id="gene_list"></textarea>
<select v-model="experiments" name="experiments" multiple id="select_result_exps">
   <!--Various <options>-->
</select>
<button name="query" v-if="canSubmit" value="search" type="submit"">Submit</button>
```

So when I change the textarea or the select, my model updates, and this means that `canSubmit` returns true. Howevever the button doesn't know that `canSubmit` has changed, so remains invisible.

Is there a way of watching a derived attribute or method in order to get this to work? Alternatively can I force the button to recheck its bindings?

Comment: It might be easier to figure the problem if you set up a simple jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason my code wasn't working was because the variables bound to the textarea and select were not considered dependencies for the canSubmit computed property.

I found this out in the [documentation here](http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#Dependency_Collection_Gotcha).

The solution, as on the site, was to access those variables initially, e.g.

```
enableSubmit: function () {
    this.genesString; //Adding these
    this.gene_search.experiments; //lines fixed the problem 

    switch (this.search_type) {
        case "gene":
            return this.genesString.length > 0 && this.gene_search.experiments.length > 0;
        case "experiment":
            return this.experiment_search.experiment.length > 0;
        default:
            return false;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 6):

This works correctly in the latest 0.11 version!

Comment: This was the "Dependency Collection Gotcha" that I missed the first few reads through the documentation. Could you make a formal list of dependencies for each computed property perhaps?

Comment: Also the most recent release is v0.10.6, which is what I'm using.

Comment: @Miguel 0.11-rc is available on github in its own branch. Latest development is happening in the "next" branch. 0.11.0 will be out soonish. In 0.11 you no longer need to list the dependencies in computed properties.